# Spring Batch GridTaskPartition not working for partitioner scope=step

Tags: spring-batch

I have the following config and code  in spring batch. I receive the exception.

```
<step id="PROCESS_FILE_TO_STAGING_TABLE_PARALLEL" next="limitDecision" >
<partition handler="partitionHandler" step="filestep" partitioner="filepartitioner" />
</step>

<bean id="partitionHandler"
class="sa.com.mobily.loader.partition.gridgain.GridGainPartitionHandler" />

<bean id="filepartitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner" scope="step" >
<property name="resources" value="#{dataMapprocessFiles}"/>
</bean>
```

code
**PartitionProvider**

```
public class PartitionProvider {

private final StepExecutionSplitter stepSplitter;
private final StepExecution stepExecution;

public PartitionProvider(StepExecutionSplitter stepSplitter, StepExecution stepExecution) {
this.stepSplitter = stepSplitter;
this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}

public String getStepName() {
return stepSplitter.getStepName();
}

public Set<StepExecution> getStepExecutions(int gridSize) throws JobExecutionException {
return stepSplitter.split(stepExecution, gridSize);
}
```

**GridGainPartitionTask**

```
public class GridGainPartitionTask extends GridTaskSplitAdapter<PartitionProvider, Collection<StepExecution>> {

@GridLoggerResource
private GridLogger log = null;

@Override
protected Collection<? extends GridJob> split(int gridSize, PartitionProvider stepSplit) throws GridException {

log.info("Executing steps for grid size=" + gridSize);

List<GridJob> jobs = new ArrayList<GridJob>(gridSize);

final String stepName = stepSplit.getStepName();

try {
for (final StepExecution stepExecution : stepSplit.getStepExecutions(gridSize)) {
jobs.add(new GridJobAdapterEx() {
public Serializable execute() {
RemoteStepExecutor stepExecutor = new RemoteStepExecutor("classpath:sa/com/mobily/loader/job/DataLoaderJob.xml", stepName, stepExecution);
log.info("Executing step '" + stepName + "' on this node.");
return stepExecutor.execute();
}
});
}
}
catch (JobExecutionException e) {
throw new GridException("Could not execute split step", e);
}

return jobs;
}

public Collection<StepExecution> reduce(List<GridJobResult> results) throws GridException {
Collection<StepExecution> total = new ArrayList<StepExecution>();
for (GridJobResult res : results) {
StepExecution status = res.getData();
total.add(status);
}
return total;
}

}
```

**GridGainPartitionHandler**

```
public class GridGainPartitionHandler extends TaskExecutorPartitionHandler {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("mscGridGain")
private Grid grid;

public Collection<StepExecution> handle(StepExecutionSplitter stepSplitter, StepExecution stepExecution) throws Exception {
PartitionProvider partitionProvider = new PartitionProvider(stepSplitter, stepExecution);
GridTaskFuture<Collection<StepExecution>> future = grid.execute(GridGainPartitionTask.class, partitionProvider );
return future.get();
}

}
```

**RemoteStepExecutor**

```
public class RemoteStepExecutor implements Serializable {

private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

private final StepExecution stepExecution;

private final String stepName;

private final String configLocation;

public RemoteStepExecutor(String configLocation, String stepName, StepExecution stepExecution) {
this.configLocation = configLocation;
this.stepName = stepName;
this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}

public StepExecution execute() {

Step step = (Step) new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configLocation).getBean(stepName, Step.class);

logger.info("Spring Version: " + SpringVersion.getVersion());

try {
step.execute(stepExecution);
}
catch (JobInterruptedException e) {
stepExecution.getJobExecution().setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPING);
throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException("TODO: this should result in a stop", e);
}

return stepExecution;

}

public String getStepName() {
return stepName;
}

}
```

**Exception**

```
2011-11-21 09:56:40,087 458939 ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:212) Encountered an error executing the step
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use your **partitionHandler** outside step context, namely:

- You create a new thread (`ThreadPoolExecutor` / Java concurrent).
- In new thread you call `org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker#run()`
- `GridWorker` calls your `GridGainPartitionTask`
- `GridGainPartitionTask` tries to use `partitionHandler` from the Spring context.

This does not work. `partitionHandler` can only be instantiated inside Spring Batch "step" context. The correct sequence should be:

- You run a Spring Batch Job (via job launcher).
- Spring Batch get a job instance from the context, already initialized with step(s).
- A step will *lazily* instantiate a partitioner (Spring context takes care of that). Note that this instantiation is only valid from a step, e.g. step instance should be before in the calling stack.
- Then the step do the partitioning and transfer the job partition to the grid via corresponding [`PartitionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitionHandler) implementation.

Comment: i did not understand this line "A step will lazily instantiate a partitioner (Spring context takes care of that). Note that this instantiation is only valid from a step, e.g. step instance should be before in the calling stack"

Comment: That means you cannot `@Autowire` your **partitionHandler** and you can't directly get it from Spring context via `context.getBean("partitionHandler")`. It can be wired only to `Step` instance, because it's instantiation is liked with step context. Think about this differently: what should be the value of `#{dataMapprocessFiles}` in **partitionHandler** if it is instantiated somewhere else? Mind that you may have many steps (and many jobs), each with its own setting and with it's own context state in runtime (e.g. when they are run in parallel).

Comment: dma_k:Thanks , #{dataMap\[processFiles\]} contains a Resource array with 10 file reference.

Comment: If your `#{dataMap[processFiles]}` is constant (i.e. it refers the property that you've defined somewhere else in you Spring context), then remove `scope="step"` from your **partitionHandler** bean declaration and be happy!